# Getting error 500 instead of 401 on token expire in Hapi-auth-jwt2

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am using Hapi-auth-jwt2 and facing an issue after my JWT expire, instead of getting a 401 error I am getting 500 server error,

Here is my code:

```
const prepare = async () => {
if(prepared){
    return;
}
await server.register(documentor as any);
server.auth.strategy('token','jwt',{
    key:JWT_TOKEN,
    validate: AuthService.verify,
    verifyOptions:{
        algorithms:['HS256']
    }
});
server.auth.default('token');
server.validator(Joi);
server.route(routes);
prepared = true;}
```

it is working fine if token is valid, but in case of invalid token it suppose to return 401, but i am getting 500, if i am using `ignoreExpiration: true` in `verifyOptions` it is again working.

this is related to [#328](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/issues/328), since i am using v10.2.0 it is suppose to be fixed, still not working in my case.

Also in case of invalid token or expired token `validate: AuthService.verify` is not getting called.

I don't know what is wrong with it. Please help.

Here is a debug error message if that helps

```
Debug: auth, unauthenticated, error, token 
Error: Expired token
at Object.raiseError (/Users/tinkeshwar/Sites/proj/tool/node_modules/hapi-auth-jwt2/lib/index.js:302:45)
at Object.internals.authenticate (/Users/tinkeshwar/Sites/proj/tool/node_modules/hapi-auth-jwt2/lib/index.js:171:26)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at Object.authenticate (/Users/tinkeshwar/Sites/proj/tool/node_modules/hapi-auth-jwt2/lib/index.js:353:22)
at exports.Manager.execute (/Users/tinkeshwar/Sites/proj/tool/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/toolkit.js:60:28)
at module.exports.internals.Auth._authenticate (/Users/tinkeshwar/Sites/proj/tool/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/auth.js:258:30)
at Request._lifecycle (/Users/tinkeshwar/Sites/proj/tool/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:372:32)
at Request._execute (/Users/tinkeshwar/Sites/proj/tool/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:280:9)
```

Debug: internal, error
ValidationError: "attributes" is not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 statusCode: Joi.any().optional().example(401),
 error: Joi.any().example("Unauthorized"),
 message: Joi.any().example("Missing authentication"),
 attributes: {error: "Expired token"}
}).label("Unauthorized Error");
```

you should probably compare your schema for the unauthorized responses.

Comment: Thanks, Prince, You saved me, I was so obsessed with the problem I didn't consider it.